# There isn't any satisfying French translation of the verb 'to groan', or is there?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, verbes

The most common French translations for the English verb *to groan* are *gémir* and *geindre*, but this implies weak, rather high-pitched sounds.

*Gronder* is one as in *le tonnerre gronde* with the right pitch, but which is more a way of showing discontent than pain. So is *grommeler*. *Râler* is a noise from the lungs rather than from the belly, which seems to me to be where *a groan* originates.

Any idea?

Comment: "Grogner" maybe ?

Comment: "to groan" can mean a couple different things depending on the context, but regardless of the case I've never thought of groaning to be "high-pitched." Providing some context might help you find the right word on this site.

Comment: Due to both their phonological and meaning proximity, I always thought groan originate from *grogner*, thanks for clearing that mistake!

Answer (score 2):

[*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/groan/584633) and [*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/groan) both refer to [*gémir*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A9mir) for groaning (of pain). Saying that *gémir* implies weak/high-pitch sounds is not entirely accurate:

> Pousser un, des [cri](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/cri)(s) [étouffé](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9touff%C3%A9/1)(s) et [plaintif](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/plaintif)(s) exprimant une douleur ou un malaise physique.

A [*gémissement*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/g%C3%A9missement/36473?q=g%C3%A9missement#36424) could be *faible* (weak), *long, aigu* (high pitched), *étouffé* (muffled), *profond* (deep), *sourd* (dull), *rauque* (hoarse), *douloureux* (painful), or *lamentable* ([plaintive](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plaintive&allowed_in_frame=0)) ([TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A9missement)). The *grognement* (*grogner*) is associated with the sound the pig, the wild boar, the bear, and by extension the dog, or even the hedgehog, make ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/grogner/38357?q=grogner#38295), [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/grogner)) i.e. growling. It can be used by analogy for a human being making dull, muffled, thudding, or generally inarticulate sounds : « *Son mari grognait de douleur dans son sommeil.* » (Zola). With *gémir* that reference to pain is also [common](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/g%C3%A9mir) whether that's redundant or not. See Books ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=g%C3%A9mir%20de%20douleur%2Churler%20de%20douleur%2Cgargouiller%2C*_NOUN%20plaintif%2C*_NOUN%20plaintive%2Cpleur%2Ccri%20de%20mort%2C*_NOUN%20%C3%A9touff%C3%A9%2C*_NOUN%20%C3%A9touff%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)) for further contextual cues (including *cri de mort*, which I know from I know not where).

As another [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18176) points out, *groan* doesn't originate from the belly, if but metaphorically speaking, but rather from Proto-Germanic *grain-, by imitation or related to *grin*, and with the Old Norse cognate *grenja* "to howl" (Etymonline). *To groan* is neither *to growl* nor *to howl*, but [*hurler*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/hurler) in French most definitely has the high-pitch association (dog, wolf) and meaning (*Pousser des cris aigus et prolongés*, [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/hurler)) compared to *gémir*. But because of polysemy and varied usage scenarios, personally I wouldn't restrict my choice of verb/noun (*crier/gémir/hurler/grogner/cri/gémissement/hurlement/grognement*) based on pitch perception but rather usage and context, such as manner, intensity and cause etc. *Cri, plainte, pleur, [râle](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18175), sanglot, soupir* are mentioned in the *TLFi* entry for *gémissement* as being in the same sort of semantic field and can prove useful depending on context. When one wants to avoid using adverbs which may feel less casual in a verb construction, you can resort to using another verb to introduce the noun with the adjective instead, in particular [*pousser*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/pousser) as in *pousser un cri/un gémissement plaintif* for instance, instead of *gémir plaintivement*. Finally, when one discusses *anger* rather than pain, there is [*tonner*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/tonner) which is really used for some sort of *angry rant* yet carries that thunderous (i.e. *tonnerre*) sort of idea you refer to with [*gronder*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gronder) which cannot be used in this fashion with a person nowadays (could still be said of an animal though).

---

The Q&A shows a myriad of verbs and adjectives with seemingly endless possible combinations where one can fine tune the property of the sound such as its (low) pitch etc., which is really the opposite of what the question title implies. The *gémissement* is not restricted to a high-pitched sound,  unlike with the base meaning for *hurlement*, or weak per se; it is not a [*mélopée*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9lop%C3%A9e). One can have a construction with [*pousser* + *un cri/gémissement* + adjective ex. *sourd*] instead of [verb + adverb] if one so requires. *Gémir de douleur* doesn't appear that far off the mark, bar a very specific context (which was not provided). Satisfaction is a matter of opinion but I would say I'm quite satisfied with the rich semantics and lexicon, and then some...

> Il faut se battre! *gargouilla* la voix rauque d'un corps qui, depuis
>   notre réveil, se prétrifiait dans la boue dévoratrice. Il le faut ! — 
>   Et le corps se retourna pesamment. [...]
>
> [ H. Barbusse, [*Feu*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pl0OCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=barbusse%20feu&pg=PT329#v=onepage&q=gargouilla&f=false), in the *TLFi* at [*gargouiller*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gargouiller), inspired from a prior edit to another [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/18175/2) ]

Answer (score 1):

***Râler*** : faire entendre un *râle* en respirant :

> *Râlant*, brisé, livide, et mort plus qu'à moitié - V.Hugo

*Râle* : bruit rauque de la respiration chez certains moribonds :

> L'abominable *râle*, cette respiration mécanique [...] derniers souffles du corps - R.Rolland

La traduction donnée par le Collins *[français - anglais](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/r%C3%A2ler)* indique *to groan* (émettre un son), alors que dans l'autre sens, *râle*r n'est pas mentionné !

---

*Références issues du petit Robert.*

Comment: Groan décrit le bruit fait par une personne qui souffre - c'est très loin du gargouillis ! En anglais le gargouis de l'estomac se rend par  *rumbling* (et celui de l'eau par *gurgling*).

Comment: @Laure - J'ai pris en compte votre commentaire, et supprimé *gargouiller*

Comment: Mais l'impayable Barbusse (pour la postérité) : _Il faut se battre! gargouilla la voix rauque d'un corps._ (au [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gargouiller))

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Beau doublet, malheureusement je ne connais pas de verbe pour *rauque* qui qualifie le timbre d'une voix. Les cordes vocales ne vibrent pas obligatoirement dans un *râle*, cela peu provenir de la gorge et non du larynx, ou des bronches. Après le commentaire de Laure et la traduction du Collins, qui correspond à la question posée, j'ai ajouté *râler* et enlevé *gargouiller* qui se passe en dessous du diaphragme... Je laisse aussi en commentaire *borborygmes* parmi les possibilités sonores du corps :)

Answer (score 1):

[Groan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=groan) can be used to express either grief or pain. When expressing pain, the French usually use *gémir*, when expressing grief the French usually use *geindre*. In  neither case would we use *gronder*.